# restrict access to directory in public folder of laravel for Authenticated users only

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose we have a `Forms` directory in `public` folder of laravel.

And Now I want to only Authenticated users can access to that and if an unauthorized user want opens that or one of it's sub directory (such as images, videos and etc) an error message shown.

I added a route group like this but does not work properly :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'Forms', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
      // what Can I do here ?  
});
```

What Can I do for that?

Comment: What is it a user would be doing inside the "forms" folder?

Comment: @scottevans93, some other subdirectories contains image and videos that I want just authorized user can access those

Comment: You would have to serve them using your controller otherwise direct HTTP access would not be controlled by your Laravel Auth System

Answer (score 1):

i would say you need to use local disk instead of public folder if you want to hide content from the user. take a look at here 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem

still if you want to restrict the directory you can use wildcard route

for ex.

```
Route::get('/forms/{path?}', function () {
    if(!auth()->user()) {
        return 'unauthorized';
    }
    // if authenticated try to look for the file with requested path and return its content
    return File::get(public_path(ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/')));
})->where(['path' => '.*']);
```