# prevent direct url access to files inside storage folder in laravel 5

Tags: url, laravel-5, storage

I'm developing an apllication in laravel 5.4
There are many pdf and other documents inside storage directory under laravel root directory. Now anyone can view or download these files using the url to that file.
eg: http://localhost/ssrteam/storage/app/hei/clarificationfiles/100013_227.pdf

I want to restrict the access to all files under storage from unauthenticated users. Only logged in user should see the files even with direct url

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40864991/320487

Comment: Possible duplicate of [restrict access to directory in public folder of laravel for Authenticated users only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40862656/restrict-access-to-directory-in-public-folder-of-laravel-for-authenticated-users)