# How do I check whether a user is authenticated before accessing/viewing a file from the filesystem public disk?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am using laravel filesystem for storing and retrieving files. `public/storage` is symlinked to `storage/app/public`. Under the `storage/app/public` directory I have two folders with the respective files (so that these can be accessed in the browser):

1. logos

   - ABC.png
   - DEF.png
2. protected-files

   - file1.pdf
   - file2.pdf

When a user tries to access files from `protected-files` directory, I would like to check whether that user is authenticated. Will we be able to do that?

I followed the answer in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40862656/restrict-access-to-directory-in-public-folder-of-laravel-for-authenticated-users/40864991#40864991), but no effect at all.

`web.php`

```
Route::get('storage/protected-files/{file}', function() {
   //logic to check whether the user is authenticated
})->where(['file' => '.*']);
```

Comment: What is actual public url to access these files not including path `storage/protected-files`?

Comment: @LovepreetSingh the actual public path to file1.pdf is `storage/protected-files/file1.pdf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web server will return the file if it exists in /public directory, The request will not even come to laravel.

So you have to move files from `/storage/app/public` directory to `/storage/app/xxxx` directory. and do the same authentication.

You can use 'local' disk which writes to storage/app directory, so you have to specify directory while writing the file.

Comment: Thanks Jithin, was thinking the same. How do I configure the new disk? should I keep that same as `public`?

'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

Comment: You can use 'local' disk, which by default writes to `/storage/app`

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks @JithinJose.

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing the files you can simply check if the user is authenticated using this code.

```
Auth::check():
```

Answer (score 0):

`storage/protected-files` path refers to location of files on server, but actually this is accessible to public world as `http://example.com/file-name.pdf`. Routes in laravel are designed to handle URL. So should try like:

```
Route::get('/{file}', function() {
    //check whether the user is authenticated
    if (!auth()->user()) { //    or may use Auth::check();
        return 'unauthorized';
    }
})->where(['file' => '.*']);
```

Comment: Hi @LovepreetSingh I have specified the 'url' in the filesystem config for public disk

'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],